# Does passing by const reference really save the memory cost when it has to convert the type?

Tags: c++, memory-management, const-reference

There are many existing questions about `const` reference (reference to const). But when there is an implicit conversion, `const` reference also causes a new address. I wrote this example bellow:

```
int i = 42;     
double d = 4.2;     
const int& ri1 = i;     
const int& ri2 = d;
```

`&ri1` and `&i` would print the same address, however `&ri2` and `&d` are different. What's the object that `ri2` really serves for? As *"C++ Primer"* says, it generates a temporary object. But if the converted const reference uses the difference address, that means this address still has a valid object.

Suppose I have a big long `string` or `const char*` as "long example text" and pass it to some function that accepts `const string&`, there would be the similar conversion.

Comment: `const int& ri2 = d;` creates a temporary `int`, with life-extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is helpful to think this way:

We would not want to bind a *(plain)* `&` reference to an object if this binding will cause this object to change. E.g. from 3.1415 to 3, like here:

```
double pi = 3.1415; 
int& r = pi; // Imagine, now both r and pi are 3...
```

We can't change the type of the `r` to `double` *(otherwise, that would be quite a logic for the language!)*.

And I'm sure most of the C++ users would not want to have the value of the referred to `pi` to change to 3 (since `r` is `int`) just as a consequence of the reference binding.

We need to create a new object by converting the `pi` to the type of the `r`. When we have a conversion happened, the reference will be bind to a temporary object created as a result of this conversion.

There will be no reason to have a non-`const` reference to this unnamed object to which we have no other *(except for the reference "handle")* access. If we some reason would like it to change, we could just copy the `pi` into an `int i` and change the `i` to whatever we want.

#### The key point for an answer to your question:

*Yes, it will create an additional burden*, in case of *from* `const char*` *to* `const string&`, but it is probably **not a case of the intended use** of the `const string&`.

Why? Because if you know for sure that, say, your function will be passed a `const char*` (and only it) and that you can't afford any overhead whatsoever, why would you declare a parameter like `const string&`. *Well, there may be several valid reasons, and all of them will be **worth having an overhead**.*

In other cases, when a `string` is passed, you will avoid copying. Win-win situation, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed an unnamed `int` object, with the value 4. That takes a bit of memory.

For the `std::string` example, a `const string&` can bind to the `string` argument without causing a copy. But the `const char*` argument will cause a copy. You could consider a `std::string_view`.